# Stone–Čech compactification of a space removing a point in a compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $x \in X$ be a non-isolated point.

In the proof of Lemma 3.1 in "[Norming $C(\Omega)$ and Related Algebras](https://doi.org/10.2307/1997632)" by B. E. Johnson it seems to be asserted  that the Stone–Čech compactification of $X \setminus \{x\}$ is considered as the space of all ultrafilters of non-empty relative closed sets of $X \setminus \{x\}$.

I don't know how to topologize this space and how to show that the space is the Stone–Čech compactification.

I thought that the topology is same as Stone space of Boolean algebra.
However, the lack of "complements" of the algebra of non-empty relative closed sets of $X \setminus \{x\}$ makes it difficult to show the compactness.

Comment: If we're working with nice enough space, then the construction using ultrafilters gives the Stone-Čech compactification. Wikipedia: [Wallman compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallman_compactification) and [Stone–Čech compactification § Construction using ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Construction_using_ultrafilters). (Certainly, there are other sources where this can be found.) So then the question is basically whether we know that $X\setminus\{x\}$ is normal.

Comment: The Wallman's construction and the relation to $\beta X$ is given in [Corollary 3.6.23 in Engelking](https://www.google.com/search?q=engelking+%223.6.23%22),
and [Problem 19K in Willard](https://books.google.com/books?id=UrsHbOjiR8QC&pg=PA142).